# follow-on to: C# Linq string compare with indexOf

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

I asked an MS SQL question that was answered >[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46346967/c-sharp-linq-string-compare-with-indexof)<.  This is a follow-on question.  In essence it is the same except the database is MySQL not MS SQL and the object of the LINQ query is a `view` and not a table.

My question now is about EF queries to MySQL databases.  I am doing a very similar query but the backend is a MySQL database `view` instead of a table.  I am trying to use the exact same construct used for the MS SQL table and have:

```
    from myView in db.companySessions
    where myView.machine.ToUpper().Substring(0,
            (int) SqlFunctions.CharIndex(myView.machine, "."))
        .Equals(machine.ToUpper().Substring(0,
            (int) SqlFunctions.CharIndex(machine.ToUpper(), ".")))
```

`db.companySessions` points to a view in a MySQL database.
`machine` is a string passed into and validated by the method.  I get the exception:

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 IndexOf(System.String,
System.StringComparison)' method, and this method cannot be translated into
a store expression.
```

Is this because I am reaching into a `view` or reaching to MySQL?

Comment: If you use .net Core I'll bet it's because of MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that `machine` is a local variable

```
var thisMachineName = SomehowGetMachineName().ToUpper().Split('.').First();
```

so you don't need to be using the `SqlFunctions` on that variable:

```
from myView in db.companySessions
where myView.machine.ToUpper().Substring(0,
        (int) SqlFunctions.CharIndex(myView.machine, "."))
    .Equals(thisMachineName)
```

Comment: I am getting the same thing after taking your advice.  Now the only `CharIndex` is on the view string `myView.machine`.

Comment: I had to rework the view to only store the "split" machine name.  That let me change the LINQ query to: `myView.machine.ToUpper().Equals(machine)`.  That lets me move forward but I don't understand the issue.  Maybe this is just one of those grey areas between LINQ and MySQL.