# LINQ to select values from a db

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I was wondering it is possible to use LINQ to select values from a list with some logic e.g. if I had postcodes EC1V 2DD, EC1M 51D..... how would I use var list.Select(rs => rs.Postcodes.Select()).ToList() to create a list of postcodes with only the first characters before the space? Thanks!

Comment: How would you write it in SQL? Then translate that to Linq. See [C# Linq string compare with indexOf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46346967/c-sharp-linq-string-compare-with-indexof), for example.

Comment: Welcome to `StackOverflow`. Please refer to the `How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example` so the comunity can help you with your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a list of postcodes for testing purposes 
And I split the the space and select the first element, of course you need to validate when doesn't have any space or something like that. Hope this can help you.

```
    List<string> postcodes = new List<string>();
    postcodes.Add("EC1V 2DD");
    postcodes.Add("EC1M 51D");

    var query = postcodes.Select(x => x.Split(' ')[1]).ToList();
    foreach(var item in query)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! lifesaver!

Comment: By the way what does the [1] after the split mean?

Comment: Oh it's because Split gives me an array of the strings in this case ["EC1V", "2DD"], so we're gonna select the second element of the array [1].